# Bad Reopen Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed an audit for the following question: *[How to generate puzzles to 'crack the code'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490525/how-to-generate-puzzles-to-crack-the-code)*

I voted *Leave Closed* because it is too broad, asking for algorithm without any attempt to solve the problem.

Is this a bad audit?

Comment: Remember that the best way to deal with audits you disagree with is by acting on them outside of the queue. Votes can take an item out of the audit pool. And you are dealing with the problem directly.

Comment: I can see why visitors would find that question interesting and therefor upvoted. Today you can get a score of +7 if you post a recipe for Roast Chicken and stumble on 7 Roast lovers. The question is too broad for SO. Maybe it does fit one of the computer science sites.